# Android 11 update for Samsung Galaxy S10 devices

Tags: updates, samsung-galaxy-s-10, android-11

When will an update come to Android 11 for Samsung Galaxy S10 devices?

Currently Android 10 is installed.

Answer (score 0):

The update is currently in preview on this devices. The update is planned starting in January 2021 (this month)_ and will be the second update of the OS.